# how to get the current location when starting applicatiion?

Tags: android, location

I want to have the current user GeoLocation but everytime I run my application it takes the last accessed user GeoLocation. How can I get the latest user GeoLocation using Network Service or GPS?
I have removed updates while exiting the application but still its taking the last user location.
 Is there anyway to get the current user location as the application starts freshly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the application starts, there is no guarantee that the current location has even been found. Using the last location is the fastest way to get a location, however if you want the current location, you must wait until a location is found. You can do this be `implementing` [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html), and `overriding` [onLocationChanged(Location)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29).

Answer (score 0):

Put up this code long time back: https://github.com/a85/LocationDetector/blob/master/src/com/rickreation/locationdetector/HomeActivitiy.java

It first tries to get the last known location and then refines the estimate by waiting for a fresh location.